# Use SELECT result for another query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way other than using a cursor that I can use `SELECT` results for a subsequent `INSERT/UPDATE` query?

Something like:

```
DECLARE @SELECTRESULT;

SELECT Something into @SELECTRESULT
FROM Somewhere

INSERT INTO SomewhereElse (X, XX, XXX)
SELECT Something, GETDATE(), 'XXX'
FROM @SELECTRESULT

UPDATE Somewhere
Set SomethingElse = 'ABC'
WHERE
Something in
(SELECT Something FROM @SELECTRESULT)
```

The reason is that I have a relatively complex query from multiple tables and I don't want duplicate this code, once for the insert and second time for the update.

Comment: Depending on the [requirement][1]  you can use a temp table or table variable. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597309/what-is-the-difference-between-temporary-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a table variable.

Something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
Col1 INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT Col1
FROM Table
```

Have a look at

[Table Variables In T-SQL](http://odetocode.com/Articles/365.aspx)

[DECLARE @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a temporary table it's ok for your case :

> SELECT Something into #temporary_table FROM Somewhere WHERE blabla

Answer (score 0):

use a temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
Something int NOT NULL,
CurrentDate DateTime NULL,
    XXX Varchar(50)
)
```

Then use your complex query on multiple tables and insert the result set into the tempTable.

```
Insert into #tempTable
-- Complex Select Query
```

Just make sure that the columns returned by the selected query match in the order as per the #tempTable structure. Also the number of columns should match.
Once you have #tempTable with the complex data, you can use it multiple number of times for insert and update queries.

```
INSERT INTO SomewhereElse (X, XX, XXX)
SELECT * from #tempTable

UPDATE Somewhere
Set SomethingElse = 'ABC'
WHERE
Something in (SELECT Something FROM #tempTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SELECTRESULT table(Something nvarchar(50)) --the data that you could reuse.
insert into @SELECTRESULT(Something)
SELECT Something
FROM Somewhere

INSERT INTO SomewhereElse (X, XX, XXX)
SELECT Something, GETDATE(), 'XXX'
FROM @SELECTRESULT

UPDATE Somewhere
Set SomethingElse = 'ABC'
WHERE Something in
(SELECT Something FROM @SELECTRESULT)
```