# Difference between temporary table's in Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

What is the difference between different types of temporary table's in Sql Server 2008?

1.) #table
2.) ##table
3.) CTE
4.) @table variable

Comment: CTEs aren't a form of temporary table.

Comment: *sigh* Ever heard of "searching the internet"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

here are some good article on TempTable VS Table Variable

1. [What is the difference between TEMPORARY TABLE and TABLE VARIABLE in SQL 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597309/what-is-the-difference-between-temporary-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-2008)
2. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/15/sql-server-difference-temptable-and-table-variable-temptable-in-memory-a-myth/
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415184/Table-Variable-V-S-Temporary-Table

**as a conclusion what i found :**

Table variables (DECLARE @t TABLE) are visible only to the
   connection that creates it, and are deleted when the batch or stored
   procedure ends.

Local temporary tables (CREATE TABLE #t) are visible
   only to the connection that creates it, and are deleted when the
   connection is closed.

Global temporary tables (CREATE TABLE ##t) are
   visible to everyone, and are deleted when all connections that have
   referenced them have closed.

Tempdb permanent tables (USE tempdb
   CREATE TABLE t) are visible to everyone, and are deleted when the
   server is restarted.

but at last i would also recommend that You should improve your internet searching.

Comment: Local temporary tables are deleted when they go out of scope - a temp table created within an `EXEC(<some query>)` will not exist when the `EXEC` has completed. A temp table created inside a stored procedure is deleted when the stored procedure returns.